# Android activity and sub-activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a menu with two buttons where each button is starting new activities. Both this activities should have the same user interface, so I want to use inheritance in order to make this happen. My idea is to create an abstract activity that the two activities extends, but I don't know how. Do I need three xml-files for the layout in the abstract class, and the layout in the two concrete classes? In my first try I only used two concrete classes where one of the classes extended the other, but the screen of activity 2 was just blank.

Hank

Comment: You can reuse the XML you have for any activity.

Comment: Show your code attempt.

Comment: If they have the same layout, you can use the same layout file. But if your second Activity is exactly the same, is there really a need for it?

Comment: How? So I just need one xml-file or should I copy?

Comment: One is translating from swedish to spanish and the other vice versa.

Comment: Just use the same xml.

Comment: Okej, by setContentView of course...Now I feel stupid. Thank you guys!